# command not found error triggered from if [ -gt ] comparsion

Tags: bash

I  was  working though the examples here http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/debugging.html  and would  like  some  help explaining the internals of why this script throws the error   [37: command not found

```
#!/bin/bash
# ex74.sh

# This is a buggy script.
# Where, oh where is the error?

a=37

if [$a -gt 27 ]
then
  echo $a
fi  

exit $?   # 0! Why?
```

Comment: `[$a` -> `[ $a` . you need space after `[` and before `]`

Comment: thanks, why do I  need  a space, what  does bash interpreter  think  [$a  is?

Comment: In old days `[` was a command which has same function for `test`. it is currently a builtin-command but `[` residues in `/usr/bin/[`. so `test $a -gt 27 ]` is good but `test$a -gt 27]` is bad. as same for `[$a`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if [ $a -gt 27 ]
    ^
    |
    add space here
```

The reason for the spaces after `[` is because `[` is also not syntax. It is a simple command. Usually a builtin of the shell. The shell executes the command `[` with the rest as parameters, including the ] as mandatory last parameter. If you do not put a space after `[` the shell will try to execute `[whatever` as command and fail.

The reason for space before the ] is similar. Because otherwise it will not be recognized as a parameter of its own.